# sub-bucket in AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, subdirectory, bucket

I'm starting with AWS S3, I already created a bucket, but I do not know how to manage it.
For example, bucket named: testing, then I'd like to create a sub-bucket named: company1, company2.

In each of sub-bucket, I'm gonna put my document on it, like doc1.pdf, doc2.pdf, etc.

However, I cannot' find any documents about sub-folder or sub-bucket.

Any helps will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, there is no concept of creating a bucket within a bucket or sub-buckets, you can find more information on [Bucket Restrictions and Limitations](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html).

But AWS S3 supports the concept of folders inside buckets, [Read more here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/FolderOperations.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this beginners guide

AWS S3 basics - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/gsg/AmazonS3Basics.html

Putting/Adding an object in bucket  - 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/gsg/PuttingAnObjectInABucket.html

Viewing an object  - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/gsg/OpeningAnObject.html

Move an object to other location - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/gsg/CopyingAnObject.html

Delete an object from bucket  - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/gsg/DeletingAnObjectandBucket.html